# "Covariate must have unique values within groups for corCAR1 objects?" Can't find the mistake

Tags: nlme

I try to analyze an `ESM-Data-Frame`, but have huge problems with my `time-Variable`?

I am getting this error message:

> covariate must have unique values within groups for corar1 objects

I really don't know what to do?

I created the time differences in hours:

```
final$zeit_ref_1 = difftime(time_1, zeit1, units='hours')
final$zeit_ref_1 
## Time differences in hours
##    [1]   0.000000   6.115833  10.131667  22.661667  25.683333  27.605278
##    [7]  31.344444  31.975000  45.032500  47.509167  70.965000  73.723056
##   [13]  73.912222  80.163889  95.492500  98.698333  99.513889 102.221667
##   [19] 104.366389 119.118889 121.563611 123.370278 128.050556 142.080833
```

And this is the model I tried to run:

```
lme(gluecklich ~ angenehm, data = final, random = ~1|Subject_ID, correlation = corCAR1(form=~zeit_ref_1|Subject_ID))
```

King regards,
Christoph

Comment: Did you find a solution to this error?